# How to go beyond the 'export to pdf' dialog box when I'm saving a pdf file in vba

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I don't want to see the 'export to pdf' dialog box  that appears when I'm saving the pdf from the print pages of the various worksheets of the workbook. 
Thats' because the dialog box simply interrupt the macro. Is it possible to avoid that? thanks in advance

```
InitialFileName:="U:\KClients\\" & nome_linea & ".pdf", FileFilter:="PDF files,*.pdf",Title:="Export to pdf")
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code or an [mcve]. This line of code is even not a complete statement. We need to see what you did in order to see what you actually did wrong.

Comment: I don't know if I explained the problem, but  I would like to produce a pdf file as output from the different print area of some worksheets in the workbook

Comment: But you didn't show the code you used for that. Since this is not a coding service you should show what you have done. The code you show is just a list of parameters which doesn't help us to understand what you have done already. • This site is to support/help you to solve the issue on your own, but not to provide ready to use code. So we can help you to fix/improve your code, but only if you show it.